# Theoretical proof of the Bohr's postulates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

It was proved in an experimental way that

1. the energy of a photon equals $E = h \nu$
2. electrons radii satisfy the equation $mvr = n \hbar$

Is it possible to prove these properties in a theoretical way?

Comment: No mate these are postulates, although the second can be proven from the first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "proving a postulate" theoretically, because your proof will always need to start from somewhere. What you can hope for is to show that a set A of postulates, which seems clunky and *ad hoc*, actually follows from a simpler set B of postulates.

The clearest example of this is when Einstein showed that the Lorentz transformations, which were clunky and seemed bizarre, actually followed from two clearly-phrased, simple postulates. (I.e.: "The laws of physics are identical for all inertial observers" and "The speed of light is a law of physics".) Having such clear explanations as the theoretical underpinnings of a vast range of experimentally observed phenomena gives us confidence that the explanations are 'right' (whatever that means).

For Bohr's postulates the situation is not so good. The postulates as phrased by Bohr can be derived from what are known as the [Postulates of Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics). These come in multiple flavours depending on who you ask, but the various versions are generally equivalent.

These postulates are relatively clunky and they are not by any means intuitive. Depending on who you ask, they also have some problems with internal consistency (in particular, the postulates themselves do not specify what they mean by "measurement"; this is called the [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem) and it is still wide open). The hope then remains that these postulates can themselves be derived from a simpler (hopefully more consistent) set of assumptions about reality. This is an active field of research but there's nothing like a definitive answer yet.